# AngularFire: Resuming an anonymous session

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

From the [Simple Web Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-anonymous.html) docs, it claims you can resume a session by doing the following:

```
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
  ...
});
```

Is there an equivalent for AngularFire?

The `$firebaseSimpleLogin` constructor takes a firebase reference as its only parameter..

Specifically, what I'm trying to do is login once anonymously and resume that login on a full page refresh. Is that achievable?

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not your auth session is preserved is determined by the parameters you pass into the login method. Whether you use FirebaseSimpleLogin or $firebaseSimpleLogin is irrelevant here.

```
var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
$rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function(user) {
   console.log('logged in', user.uid);
});

// automagically logs in the next time you call $firebaseSimpleLogin() after page refresh
auth.$login('anonymous', { rememberMe: true });

// does not automagically log in
auth.$login('anonymous');
```

**UPDATE** As of Angular 1.x and Firebase 2.x this syntax and behavior has changed.

From the `remember` attribute in Firebase docs:

> If not specified - or set to `default` - sessions are persisted for as
>   long as you have configured in the Login & Auth tab of your App
>   Dashboard. To limit persistence to the lifetime of the current window,
>   set this to `sessionOnly`. A value of `none` will not persist
>   authentication data at all and will end authentication as soon as the
>   page is closed.

```
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
$firebaseAuth.$onAuth(function(user) {
   console.log('logged ' + (user? 'in' : 'out'), user && user.uid);
});

// stays logged in for length specified in the app dashboard
auth.$authAnonymously();

// stays logged in until the browser closes
auth.$authAnonymously({ remember: 'sessionOnly' });

// does not stay logged in on page refresh
auth.$authAnonymously({ remember: 'none' });
```